# Finding multiple instances in multiple columns

Tags: excel

in Excel I wish to sort and filter some entries from multiple columns in a single column.
The table looks like this:

```
    Day    Product.ID Quantity Time Product.ID Quantity Time Product.ID Quantity Time  
    1/1/17 9987/7     2500     8    11774      500      12   447/77     1400     4 
    2/1/17 9987/7     2350     8    2248/5     600      11   9987/7     1400     4 
    3/1/17 2248/5     3500     7    11774      650      12   447/77     1400     4 
    6/1/17 447/77     5500     8    11774      550      10   447/77     1400     4 
    7/1/17 9987/7     2000     6    2248/5     500      12   11774      1400     4
```

I would like to generate a "query" where I can have a report in a similar fashion:

```
    Product.ID: 9987/7 (drop down menu)
    Day    Quantity Time
    1/1/17 2500     8
    2/1/17 2350     8
    2/1/17 1400     4
    7/1/17 2000     6
```

And from there I can extrapolate all my data and conclusions. I know how to do it checking a single column and `INDEX` or `VLOOKUP` the other cells but I can't figure out how to do it this way.
I can't transpose the data on a single column since they come from an already compiled sheet with production data from each machine.

Thank you all

Comment: Show us what you have done and where you have run into problems. Why does the source of the data make a difference in whether you can reformat the data in a new workbook into a single set of columns?

Comment: This is the basic formula I'm using to get data from the first columns

=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(1:1)),2))

I've of course changed the reference table and the outputs (this one comes from http://eimagine.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/)

I would paste the one I'm actually using but Excel is in italian so it would be a mess to understand or translate.

Comment: The data can't be reformatted in a single column since sheet1 will be updated daily with new data and not necessarely by me. For the work enviroment I'm in (low IT skills) even asking them to fill a digital form is hard enough

Comment: OK, a VBA solution would be appropriate, but the best solution would depend on what you really want to do. Simplest would be if your Query only involved choosing a `Product.ID` (as you show in your example).  Perhaps even generating a table where all of the `Product.ID` results are listed.  For `low IT skill` users, you could just present a Button to start the operation, and then a comboBox with a dropdown list; and then generate the report.  Many ways to skin this cat depending on exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to recreate your spreadsheet
And put the results in Cells L.

I wrote some quick VBA Code that might act as reference to solve your problem. You can make a button to trigger the filter function and let it populate.

[image]

```
Sub filter():
Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim product_id As String
Dim column_len, row_len As Integer

'clearing content from previous entry
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L3:N6").ClearContents

'Determining variable for row and columns
product_id = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M2").Value
column_len = Cells.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
row_len = Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
k = 3

'for loop through the columns and row to find the product_id and populate 
'the results box with Date, Product.ID and Quantity

For i = 1 To column_len
    If (Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i).Value = "Product.ID") Then
        For j = 1 To row_len
            If (Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, i).Value = product_id) Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, 12).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, 12 + 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, i).Value
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, 12 + 2).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, i + 1).Value
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try and implement it.
I'm not extremely familiar with VBA and I'll still look for a similar solution with just excel code but as a temporary solution this will probably be the best.

Comment: I've managed to look into your code and there's one issue and that's the date. it's a quick fix, `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, 12).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, i - 1).Value` should read `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, 12).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value`

Moreover in this instance it's best to check first each row and then each column but is a quick tweak.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I missed that one. I remember thinking about that  but forgot to implement it in the code. I will edit my answer.

I'm using VBA since I think excel are not designed to process that kind of data structure without changing the format or copying the report into another sheet and preprocess it. But maybe that's just my limited excel knowledge.

Comment: I'm tweaking your solution here and there (the data I'm working on are production statistics from the factory and I'm not exactly sure how much I can divulge) but I'll update with an answer as soon as I'm done with everything.